# How do I obtain a bootstrap distribution in R?

Tags: r

This is my data (number of tweets posted via different devices):

```
x = c(243,1,174)
y = c(392,0,240)
z = c(x,y)

data = matrix(z,
            ncol = 2,
            nrow = 3,
            dimnames = list(c("iPhone","Android","iPad")))
```

I need to obtain a bootstrap distribution of only the proportion of tweets posted from an iPhone, so row 1 of the matrix.

This is what I've tried doing based on what I found online:

```
x = matrix(data[1,])

f <- function(data, indices){
  dt<-data[indices,]
  c(
    cor(dt[,1], method='s'),
    median(dt[,1])
  )
}

set.seed(1000)
myBootstrap <- boot(x, f, R=1000)
```

But when I run the last line of code, I get the error: "Error in dt[, 1] : incorrect number of dimensions" which I don't understand.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. Bootstrapping with only two data points is not reasonable. Anyway, your issue is that `x[1:2,]` is a vector. You can fix that by changing to `dt<-data[indices,, drop = FALSE]`. But then you will get a (very reasonable) error from `cor`.

Comment: That's why I'm confused, but the question I have to answer states exactly to "obtain a bootstrap distribution of the proportion of the tweets posted from an “iPhone” using the table created". Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following bootstraps proportions of tweets posted via `x` and `y` on the total of tweets.

```
library(boot)

f <- function(data, indices){
  d <- data[indices]
  tbl <- table(d)
  tbl/sum(tbl)
}

x <- c(243,1,174)
y <- c(392,0,240)
data <- cbind(x, y)
rownames(data) <- c("iPhone","Android","iPad")

X <- data["iPhone", ]
Y <- rep(names(X), X)

set.seed(1000)
myBootstrap <- boot(Y, f, R = 1000)
myBootstrap$t0
colMeans(myBootstrap$t)
```